# Copy Data from Active cells to Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a total beginner here. I saw this example online to copy data from a fixed range of a workbook to another workbook.

Could someone please guide me on how I can copy from A2 cell onward to the last active cell with data?
[image: Here's an example of the data I need to copy] .

In this given example, I wanted to copy those cells highlighted in blue to another workbook. The data varies every time, hence a fixed range doesn't work for me. I try using ".UsedRange" but it copies the footer as well, which is something I don't need.

```
Sub Copy_Method()
  Workbooks("New-Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Export").Range("A2:D9").Copy _
    Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A2")

 End Sub
```

Ref: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your particular set up, you can use the [CurrentRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion) property.

```
Sub Copy_Method()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Workbooks("New-Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Export").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set r = r.Offset(1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1) 'exclude the header
r.Copy Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to CurrentRegion property, never knew how to use it. :-) This is useful when it comes to having more than 5 columns of data.

Answer (score 1):

as per the posted screenshot:

- the "footer" appears to be placed in column A
- data fill all columns from A to E

hence you can use column B to get the last used cell row from:

```
Sub Copy_Method()
   With Workbooks("New-Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Export")
       .Range("A2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
       Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A2")
   End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: @CarmenC, any feedback?

Comment: Thanks @HTH, this works like a charm, all I need to do is to make sure the last used cell of column B has no missing data.

Comment: You are welcome. If you're more confident in column C, just change `(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)` to ``(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)`. Or, if D, to ``(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)`. And you may consider marking the answer as accepted to direct future Readers, too...